# How to display distinct Value and total sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, distinct

I have table1:

[image]

Now I want to for value from column Type, count unique PiD, and display sum of Value for type. Result should me return below output:

[image]

For Type= "ABC" I have 4 unique Pid, sum(Value) = (10+20+30+40+10+50+60+20) is 240

**How to write correct SQL query?**

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select l2, fq, type, count(distinct pid), sum(value)
from your_table
group by l2, fq, type
```

Comment: thank you jurgen for so quick respone, I put distinct into wrong please, your code is working!

Answer (score -1):

select L2,FQ,Type, count(distinct pid),sum(Value) from table1 group by 1,2,3;